# MySQL SELECT WHERE X LIKE a AND NOT LIKE B

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select some data but im unable to do it in the way I need it and I cant find the issue with the query
The data is like:

```
user    | priority | group  
user-a  |    5     |  other  
user-b  |    5     |  none-a
user-b  |    2     |  some-grp
user-c  |    5     |  other-a  
user-d  |    5     |  other-b
```

basically a user can have many groups with a priority, and i whant to filter users which do NOT have a specific group

the query im using is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE group LIKE  "other%" OR group LIKE  "none%"
AND group NOT LIKE  "some%"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but this query will return all results not users a/c/d (its like ignores the AND NOT LIKE

Comment: group is a mysql reserved word. you need to use those little ticks to escape it: `group` - and in SO it's bb code for highlighting code so It looks like my smartass example failed

Comment: Is the order of precedence correct?  AND has a higher precedent than OR, so the AND is combining your last two conditions. Is that what you want?  If not, slap some parenthesis around the conditions you want to consider together.

Comment: From the way you worded your question, you can get that result without the `AND`, with just the `WHERE` clause, becaue matching `other%` or `none%` would automatically exclude those matching `some%`. As I'm sure it's not that simple, you need to [edit] your question and show the results you'd like to get from your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

may be you want this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954cc/4)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (`user` varchar(20), priority int, `group` varchar(20))
;
insert t (`user`, priority, `group`)
values ('user-a', 5, 'other'),
('user-b', 5, 'none-a'),
('user-b', 2, 'some-grp'),
('user-c', 5, 'other-a'),
('user-d', 5, 'other-b')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT `user` 
FROM t
WHERE `user` in 
  (select `user` from t 
   where `group` LIKE  "other%" OR `group` LIKE  "none%")
   and `user` not in 
  (select `user` from t 
   where `group` LIKE  "some%")
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954cc/4/0)**:

```
|   USER |
----------
| user-a |
| user-c |
| user-d |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want not to show users included in specific groups, you can use the *NOT IN with a non-correlated subquery* or the *NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery* strategies.

**NOT IN with a non-correlated subquery**

```
SELECT `user`
FROM t
WHERE (`group` LIKE  "other%" OR `group` LIKE  "none%")
   AND `user` NOT IN (SELECT `user` FROM t WHERE `group` LIKE  "some%");
```

**NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery**

```
SELECT t.`user`
FROM t
WHERE (t.`group` LIKE  "other%" OR t.`group` LIKE  "none%")
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM t sub_t
    WHERE sub_t.`user` = t.`user`
      AND sub_t.`group` LIKE  "some%" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im very new to MySQL so i will have to read about what correlated is. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join but keep only rows that *dont* join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM tableName t1
LEFT JOIN tableName t2
  ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  AND t2.group NOT LIKE "some%"
WHERE (t1.group LIKE  "other%"
OR t1.group LIKE  "none%")
AND t2.user_id IS NULL -- only non-joins
LIMIT 0, 30
```

There was also a bug in your WHERE clause with in bracketed OK conditions (fixed here) which would have led to incorrect logic due to operator precedence.

Also had to guess what there's user id column was - you may have to adjust for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to approach these using aggregation and `having`, because that is a very flexible approach.

```
select user
from t
group by user
having sum(group LIKE  'other%') > 0 or
       (sum(group LIKE 'none%' > 0 and
        sum(group like 'some%') = 0
       )
```

This basically translates your `where` clause -- which operates on one record -- in a `having` clause that counts the occurrences of each pattern in the group.